# How to know when session is close

Tags: java, database, session, web, listener

I have webapp on java with database. When user logs in, i change field status in database to authorized. When someone tries to login under the same account, it says that someone is already logged in using this account. That's why I need to change that status field to "not_authorized" when session is closed (user close the browser). I know about ServletContextListener, but they are used in application initializing and destroying. And I need the same stuff for Session. Smth like Session listener with method SessionDestroyed. Is there any way to do this? TY a lot

Comment: Does the 'session closed' mean actually a logout?

Comment: Yea, kinda like that.

Comment: What purpose are you doing this with? Does the application break somehow when users are logged in on multiple devices at once? If so, you may want to fix that break instead.

Comment: Probably you should check your web framework options, for example in Spring Security the default logout address is '/logout', so you could use sth like <a href="<c:url value="/logout" />">Logout</a>. Otherwise there is no way to detect closing a browser with normal HTTP if you are not going to hack with AJAX polling. Then you should look at WebSockets stuff.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, even though you close the browser the session will be active for some time, after session time out the session will be invalidated. So you won't get notified when somebody closes the browser. You can try using web sockets, where on close of the socket handler you can write your logic to update db.

try extending the class SessionListener, for more info follow the link http://www.groupkt.com/post/7ee95bbd/session-timeout-handling-in-java.htm

```
<webapp>
 <listeners>
    <listener-class> com.groupkt.example.AppHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
 </listeners>
</webapp>
```

Comment: I mean closing the browser is not the point. I need to change that field after session invalidation.